# Progress bar when fitting a big additive model

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

When running a big additive model in R, is there a way to incorporate a progress bar (or similar) that tells me how much time is remaining? Some of my bam's run for many hours, and so it would be nice to know when the models finish so i can account for that. I am using a laptop and have to move locations regularly.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `progressr` package by Henrik Bengtsson (https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/progressr). Without some more specifics on what your code looks like it is hard to make recommendation as to where to place the tickers. Alternatively, have a look at Rstudio jobs and its progress bar utility (https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/03/14/rstudio-1-2-jobs/)

Comment: If you're talking about a single bam call, I don't think this is possible.  I would love one too.  I've run smaller models in parallel with a progress bar from the `tcltk` package.